# JDBC driver for SAP HANA not recognized on Mac for Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, hana

I tried following the steps given in

https://www.tableau.com/en-us/support/drivers?edition=pro&lang=en-us&platform=mac&cpu=64&version=2018.1&__full-version=20181.18.0416.1335#saphana

to install the JDBC driver for SAP HANA but Tableau does not recognize the drivers I installed. I am using MacOS High Sierra version 10.13.5. The version of Tableau I am using is 2018.1.0 64-bit.

Could the driver given by my administrator be only applicable for Windows? Because that is what it is usually used for.

Update:
My administrator gave me a driver specifically for macOS containing `hdbsetup`, which I ran. The result is:

[image]

I copied the `ngdbc.jar` file to `~/Library/Tableau/Drivers` and changed permissions to `777`. When I open Tableau the drivers are not recognized:

[image]

Update2: Answer to comment

[image: Answer to comment]

Update3:
It is a known issue in Tableau 2018.1.

Comment: The driver should be a .jar file which is platform independent, so I doubt that you've been given a Windows driver by accident. Have you confirmed that the file was copied to ~/Library/Tableau/Drivers and that you have read permissions?

Comment: Yes see update2.